# How to save some state into the URL as a query parameter

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using AngularJS 1.0.7, with ui-bootstrap 1.0.4.

My application has a main navigation bar, and some pages have an extra level of tabs (using ui.bootstrap tabset and tab directives).

What I'm trying to accomplish is this:

Clicking a tab will update the URL, adding a "?tab=name" query parameter. The developer will add an additional directive to each `<tab>` element to identify the name.

When the view is loaded, something (that's the rub) will listen for the event (which event?) and update the tab, invoking the `select()` function on the tab's scope.

I've been struggling with this. Basically, the order of operations is in my way; the $routeChangeSuccess event is close to what I want BUT that is used by the ngView directive to load the content. This means that the directives that listen for $routeChangeSuccess don't exist until after the event has been broadcast.

Looking in the source, I can see there's an $viewContentLoaded event. However the timing of that is also odd.

Here's what I have:

```
module = angular.module "navigation-support", ["ui.bootstrap.tabs"]

module.directive "tabBookmark", ($log, $location, $route, $rootScope, $routeParams) ->
  restrict: "A"
  require: "^tab"
  link: (scope, element, attr, tabController) ->
    $log.log "scope=#{scope.$id}, tabController=#{tabController}, bookmark='#{attr.tabBookmark}'"

    scope.$watch "active", (newActive) ->
      if newActive
        $location.search "tab", attr.tabBookmark

    scope.$on "$destroy",
      $rootScope.$on "activateTab", (tabValue) ->
        $log.log "activateTab, tab='#{tabValue}' (looking for '#{attr.tabBookmark}')"

        if tabValue is attr.tabBookmark
          scope.select()

module.factory "TabSupport", ($log, $routeParams, $rootScope) ->
  ($scope) ->
    $log.log "TabSupport: initializing scope #{$scope.$id}"
    $scope.$on "$destroy",
      $rootScope.$on "$viewContentLoaded", ->
        tabValue = $routeParams.tab
        $log.log "TabSupport: tab changed to '#{tabValue}'"

        if tabValue
          $log.log "TabSupport: broadcasting 'activateTab'"
          $rootScope.$broadcast "activateTab", tabValue
```

To make this work, I have my view's controller invoke the TabSupport service; also I disable `reloadOnSearch`.

What I see is that even the $viewContentLoaded event is too early (perplexingly).

I then changed the code to defer the activateTab broadcast (using `$timeout`).

Now the code that watches the "active" expression triggers too early, before the activeTab event is received. This is because the tabset selects the first tab when no tab is explicitly activated.

So, can anyone suggest a better approach?  I'd prefer the value in the URL as a query parameter, but it can just as easily be in local storage or in the path ... but that isn't the problem. The problem is the order of operations for constructing the view and its nested directives.

Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: Why do people downvote with no explanation?  It's cowardly and gives the OP zero feedback.

Comment: @earcam see the edits. Nevertheless now it's a proper question so it should be upvoted.

Comment: I think it was pretty obvious I'd accidentally submitted the form prematurely.  I then did a lot more research before updating it with the missing code and description.

Answer (score 0):

I use the `$location.search()` array to hold search filter settings in an application I'm working on.  I use the below `$on` to listen for these changes and run the appropriate search.

```
$scope.$on('$routeUpdate', function () {
    ...
});
```